# How to parse dynamic json keys in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

How to parse the dynamic numeric keys with following json. I can able to do manually `json_text['entities']['0']['uid']`, how can I dynamically iterate with all keys and get all uid's

```
{
    "entities": {
        "0":{
            "uid": "3769fcb3-8312-41b8-a5c9-3c24b6a9ce96"
            },
        "1":{
            "uid": "3769fcb3-8312-41b8-a5c9-3c24b6a9ce97"
            },
        "2":{
            "uid": "3769fcb3-8312-41b8-a5c9-3c24b6a9ce98"
            }
        "3":{
            ;
            }
          :
          :
          :           
    }   
}
```

Code:

```
import os, json
import pandas as pd

path_to_json = '/home/sshuser/data/'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
print(json_files) 
# here I define my pandas Dataframe with the columns I want to get from the json

# we need both the json and an index number so use enumerate()
for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        json_text = json.loads(json_file.read())
        uids= json_text['entities']['0']['uid']
        print(seeMore)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can this

```
import json

with open ("yourfile.json","r") as f:
   json=json.load(f)
try:
   a=0
   while True:
      print(json["entities"][str(a)]["uid"])
      a+=1
except KeyError:
   pass
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_text['entities']` is a dict. You can use dict.items() to iterate over key and value pairs.

```
for key, value in json_text['entities'].items(): # assume key 'entities' always exists
    print(f"{key} --> {value.get('uid')}")
```

if `key` is not important,  you can iterate just over `.values()` instead:

```
for value in json_text['entities'].values():
    print(value.get('uid'))
```